# Paypal multiple subscriptions in one recurring billing

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is possible to assign multiple payment plans to a single billing agreement?

e.g.

The user subscribes to 3 different services:

1. sports magazine - 3months - xamount;
2. fashion magazine - 6 months - yamount;
3. music magazine - 3 months - zamount;

I have been looking, and the only option I found was creating 3 different plans, and make the user agree with the billing plan 3 times, which is not practicable.

I might even be seeing this in the wrong perspective.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the plans only once, then you just subscribe all your clients to that plans... So, to answer your question: **NO**, it's not possible.

**But** it is possible the other way around, you can assign multiple billing agreements to one plan.